# Parsing PHP with Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Has anyone found a way or plugin to reduce the time it takes for expression engine to parse php?

Using EE1

Comment: EE has its setup to parse "inline" php or included php files. Once you look at Template Debugging it will be listed under: Parsing PHP on Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - move your PHP code out of the template and into a custom plugin or module.

Comment: Currently all of the PHP just runs through an include. Can you recommend a module?

Comment: I'm talking about taking your raw PHP code and putting that to a custom EE plugin, then calling the plugin using standard EE syntax. It will be faster than PHP in the template.

Comment: Ah okay, Ill create a custom plugin.